# Is there a less "hacky" way to check an items visibility?

Tags: javascript, typescript, gulp-protractor

I am testing a single page app, the navigation page is revealed when the user clicks the appropriate icon. I wanted to check and see prior to clicking if the page is already open. On the page is a company name label. It is only actually visible to the naked eye when the navigation page is displayed.

The problem that I am running into is that `.isDisplayed()` is returning `true` when I use that. I have also used `EC.visibilityOf()` which returns `true` as well. The below works, I am just not happy with it and am wondering if there is a better way.

```
    navigationOpenClick() {
    if (this.EC.elementToBeSelected(this.navPage.companyName)) {
        this.navIcon.click();
    }
}
```

Comment: There are several ways to make the element invisible. Can you show the disabled element ? Basically you need to investigate why is your `expect($('.myclass').isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();` returning truthy. e.g. http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.isDisplayed should work

Comment: _"Is there a less “hacky” way to check an items visibility?"_ 
Yes there is. - Use the damn DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My brain had some flatulence and forgot that `.isDisplayed()` returns a promise. Once I resolved the promise, the `.isDisplayed()` worked like it should.

My not "hacky" working code is below:

```
   navigationOpenClick() {
    this.navPage.companyName.isDisplayed().then((displayed) => {
        if (!displayed) {
            this.navIcon.click();
        };
    });
}
```